# How can I use my own template file instead of default template provided by Ping Federate on IDP SLO error?

Tags: ldap, ping, saml-2.0, federated-identity, pingfederate

I have my template file named as "companyName.idp.slo.error.page.template.html" which I want to display to User instead of the default template "idp.slo.error.page.template.html" provided by Ping federate whenever IDP SLO error occurs. Is there a way for this to work?

Comment: Basically I want to rename "idp.slo.error.page.template.hmtl"(default template provided by Ping Federate whenever IDP SLO error occurs) to "companyName.idp.slo.error.page.template.hmtl" and tell Ping Federate that whenever IDP SLO error occurs then load this "companyName.idp.slo.error.page.template.hmtl" template and not the default one i.e. "idp.slo.error.page.template.hmtl" template.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't specify another SLO template to be used. PingFederate wants you to pass in the InErrorResource to the /idp/startSLO.ping Application Endpoint to specify the landing page.

Alternatively, you could customize the default SLO template to redirect to a properly customized page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you'll only use the single template (i.e. no requirement to show different templates based on context) you can replace the OOTB template with your custom one, just give it the same name (idp.slo.error.page.template.hmtl). A restart of PingFederate might be required.

And of course, it always makes sense to back up what you're replacing (the OOTB template).

Comment: Thank you @Mehmet for replying...But my requirement is to prefix the default template name(provided by Ping Federate) with company name and use it, so  "idp.slo.error.page.template.hmtl" would be renamed as "companyName.idp.slo.error.page.template.hmtl".